# Is there a way to link spreadsheet information into my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a CSV file with 3 columns and 223 rows. The columns go from items (A column), description (B column), to type (C column). Each row contains information about each item. I want to insert data from all this spreadsheet into my HTML file. Along with this, I want to save time by not copy and pasting 233 sets of information manually.

Originally the information I needed was on a website, however, I found a suggestion to use a webscraper to get all the information I needed. I did this by using python and now I have all the information in the spreadsheet.

The template I would like to follow is shown (using spreadsheet terms). If I were manually doing this the next line of code would look this but with a B instead of an A (A1->B1)

```
<p class="item-title">(A1 in spreadsheet)</p>
<p class="w-itemid">ItemID: N/A</p>
<p>&#8226;      (A2 in spreadsheet)</p>
<ul>
    <p>Type: (A3 in spreadsheet</p>
    <p>Item Pool: N/A</p>
</ul>
```

I want the solution to be able to link the information from my spreadsheet into my HTML without spending an immense amount of time copy and pasting 233 items. I do not mind using Javascript, jQuery, or PHP as long as it helps me finish this task.

Comment: it is possible to convert xls to xml or .json and then do api calls to your data.
( if you can find a way to host your .json file)

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

comment if you are not sure how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: can you share your columns and one piece of data from each? even fake data?

Comment: Sure, my .csv file does not have headers so row 1 jumps straight into the information. A4 = Agni's Sparkler, B4 = Increases ferocity of your burn status effects!, C4 = Offense. A5 = Albert's Formula, B5 = Receive signature charge when healed!, C5 = Misc. These are two separate items along with the description and type for each of them (they are on the same row).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution:

```
$row = 1;
$columnArray = [];
$resultArray = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

        if($row == 1){
            $columnArray = $data;
        }else{
            $tmpArray = [];
            for($i=0;$i<count($columnArray);$i++){
                $tmpArray[$columnArray[$i]] = $data[$i];
            }
            $resultArray[] = $tmpArray;
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I'm assuming that the first row of your CSV holds the column names. At the end you will have `$resultArray` associative array holding all your data.

**UPDATE**

If your CSV does not contain field names at the first row you can use this code:

```
$row = 1;
$resultArray = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $resultArray[] = $data;
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

In this case `$resultArray` will hold the data as a normal nested array and you can show the info by iterating trough it:

```
if(count($resultArray)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($resultArray);$i++){
        echo '<p>Item: '.$resultArray[$i][0].'</p>';
        echo '<p>Description: '.$resultArray[$i][1].'</p>';
        echo '<p>Type: '.$resultArray[$i][2].'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: My first rows of the csv do not hold the column names. Do I put this code at the bottom of my htm file or do I just make a separate file. How would I implement this code into the example template above or would I just have to scrap my template. Also could you clarify a bit on what $resultArray does?

Comment: @Godot I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: I have still been looking at it all this time. I am still trying to understand it because I am still new to using php. A bit confused on where to start. I have put this into my htm file. I tried copy and pasting it here to show you but it looked a mess so I will just type it out here. I put in between the brackets at $resultArray 233 because that is how many line I have in the csv file. If I am suppose ot remove this I can.

Comment: @Godot can you provide somehow your html code and I'll try to help you

Comment: I will try my best, but I do not know how to format in a comment section. A link is here https://github.com/users/HeartofPraxicFire/projects/1   This version does not have the php file you gave me in yet. I already had items put in but I can take them out once this code works. Hopefully you will be able to see my code since I don't think I can put it here